# Externally connect to Python socket server

Tags: python, server, connection, lan, ipv4

Clients on the same LAN can connect to the server just fine using the server machine's IPv4 address. However, when I have the clients use my router's external ip and port forward down to the server machine, they cannot connect. Any idea, as to why? I created a server and client in GML using the same port forward and it connected just fine using the external ip, so I am assuming I am missing something needed in Python. Here is the stripped down version of the server code:

```
# Server variables
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 65000
max_connections = 100
timeout = 5

# Run Server
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host, port))
socket.settimeout(timeout)
socket.listen(max_connections)
run()
```

I've tried setting the server ip to "" and "0.0.0.0" to no avail. I also tried using the default gateway ip for kicks and giggles. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus/firewalls installed? Some firewalls block incoming connections

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I turned off Windows Defender and my router's Firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up. I thought I had disabled Windows Defender's firewall, but I had only turned off real-time protection. Bah...that's what happens when you're going fast and not paying enough attention. Now it works just fine.